# Use Name of Data Frame Passed to Function as Plot Title

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a function foo that takes a data frame as input and returns a ggplot object as output. I need to use the name of the data frame as the title of the plot. I am unable to figure out how to do this.

If I did not pass it to a function, I know that I could use `deparse(substitute(df))` to get the desired title. But I am unable to do it inside the function.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not given a minimal example to show the problem. The following works for me:

```
a <- expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:2)
f <- function(df){qplot(x, y, data=a, main=deparse(substitute(df)))}
f(a)
```

Were you doing something else?